# Ng-table, hide-columns feature, can't hide columns from controller manually

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngtable

I have set up ng-table with checkbox buttons to hide columns and it works great.
here is an html

```
// switchers to hide/show columns
<div style="margin-bottom: 20px">
    <label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="col in demo.cols">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" ng-model="col.show"/> {{col.title()}}
    </label>
  </div>
// ng table self
  <table ng-table="demo.tableParams" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" ng-table-columns-binding="demo.cols">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
      <td title="'Name'" ng-if="true">{{row.name}}</td>
      <td title="'Age'" ng-if="true">{{row.age}}</td>
      <td title="'Money'" ng-if="true">{{row.money}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

*and here is controller code*

```
    // NG-TABLE PARAMS
  self.cols = [
    { field: "name", title: "Name", show: true },
    { field: "age", title: "Age", show: true },
    { field: "money", title: "Money", show: true}
  ];

  var simpleList = [{"id":1,"name":"Nissim","age":41,"money":454},{"id":2,"name":"Mariko","age":10,"money":-100},{"id":3,"name":"Mark","age":39,"money":291},{"id":4,"name":"Allen","age":85,"money":871},{"id":5,"name":"Dustin","age":10,"money":378},{"id":6,"name":"Macon","age":9,"money":128},{"id":7,"name":"Ezra","age":78,"money":11},{"id":8,"name":"Fiona","age":87,"money":285},{"id":9,"name":"Ira","age":7,"money":816},{"id":10,"name":"Barbara","age":46,"money":44},{"id":11,"name":"Lydia","age":56,"money":494},{"id":12,"name":"Carlos","age":80,"money":193}];

  self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
    filterDelay: 0,
    dataset: simpleList,
    counts: []
  });
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8TY7.png)

**Problem**

I wanted to create my own button to hide necessarry columns at once, instead of clicking to each column. To do that i created a button with function. *Here the button code*

```
<button  class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng:click="demo.hideColumns()">Hide columns</button>
```

*and here is the function inside controller*

```
self.hideColumns = function(){
    self.cols[1].show = false;
    self.cols[2].show = false;
}
```

the code above works, the checkboxes change to unchecked, but the table does not hide columns, I guess the problem somehow related to angular's `getter/setter` features, but I couldn't solve it.

Dear SO community please help me to solve this problem, 
Thank you

**Links**

[Codepen page, where I copied the code](http://ng-table.com/#/columns/demo-visibility)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `col.show` is a [getter/setter function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel#binding-to-a-getter-setter). To toggle the value change the `hideColumns` function to i.e.:

```
self.hideColumns = function(){
    self.cols[1].show(false);
    self.cols[2].show(false);
}
```

A working [plunker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adLMmR?editors=101)

Comment: thank you for response, it didn't work. Maximum call stack size exceeded error happened, and chrome crashed. Could you please provide working example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Sir, you da real MVP))) Thank you!